# Hanging Indents / Text Wrapping

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, indentation, paragraphs

I'm trying to implement a command to be used in place of the `itemize`/`enumerate` environments. The idea is that I want to have a command (`\detail`), which can be used to construct an itemized list without being contained in an environment. The problem I'm having is that when a line is longer than the page width and consequently wraps to the next line, I don't seem to have any control over the indentation of the wrapped text. I've tried the `hanging` package and `\hangindent`, but haven't had much luck.

I've included a minimum example below and the output that I get when compiled. Ideally, I would like the wrapped text to be indented such that the first word on the second line aligns with the first word of the first line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\detail}[1]{-- {#1}}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\textbf{This is a header}\\
    \detail{This is a detail.}\\
    \detail{This is a detail that has too many words in it and consequently runs onto the next line of the page, and I want it to have a hanging indent.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simplification of the already answered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\D{\par\noindent\makebox[1em][l]{-- }\hangindent1em}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{This is a header}
\D This is a detail
\D This is a detail that has too many words in it and consequently runs onto The next line of the page, and I want it to have a hanging indent.
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Ok, so this aligns perfectly whereas the previous answer did not. Can you explain to me why this works better?

Comment: @Kevin I think that is only a optical effect because the shape of the "T". In the answer of Harish Kumar,  change the "next" of the last line by "Text". Both "T" are now perfectly aligned. Try only a text with   `\noindent T\par \noindent n\par` and you will see that `n` seem also here misaligned with respect  the "T", but both characters are just in the margin!

Comment: It's not an illusion. My actual document has two capital "M"s, one directly beneath the other. With Harish Kumar's answer, the "M"s do not align, but with yours they do.

Comment: @Kevin I needed a zoom at 400% to note that, but you are right. I do not know why the result is not exactly the same.

Comment: Why is the wrapped line starting with a capital T?

Comment: @Kevin -- the reason there is not perfect alignment in the answer by harishkumar is that the space following the dash is not "fixed", so when the first line is justified, that space is stretched or compressed as necessary to make the line fit.  by putting the space in a box, it will not be included in the space-adjustment needed for justification.

Comment: @IbnSaeed Because I changed "the" by "The"  in the source text (Of course,  it is not grammatically correct,  but it is easier check visually the alignment.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton yeah, I was confused here  because also happen with `~` and I wrongly  thought in the non-break space as a fixed space.

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\detail}[1]{\par\noindent\hangindent=\mylen\hangafter1-- #1}
\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{-- }

\begin{document}
    \noindent\textbf{This is a header}
    \detail{This is a detail.}
    \detail{This is a detail that has too many words in it and consequently runs onto the next line of the page, and I want it to have a hanging indent.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! That's almost perfect. For some reason, the alignment is just a hair off, which becomes really apparent when a hanging line starts with the same letter: http://i.snag.gy/Zb3N5.jpg

Comment: @Kevin My eyes are pretty bad. Try with `\settowidth{\mylen}{--\space}`

Comment: Nope, that has the same effect. I tried with other bullet icons in case it was the en dash that was messing it up, but they still don't come out exactly aligned.

Comment: @HarishKumar -- the space after the dash will be included in the justification process, so unless all the spaces after the justification are absolutely equal to the "natural" width, that initial space will cause the first letter of the text to be out of line with the hanging indent.  put it in a box.  (the `\settowidth` works, because that will use the "natural" width of the space.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I doubted that. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\detail}[1]{\par\noindent\hangindent=\mylen\hangafter1--\,\,#1}
\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{--\,\,}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\textbf{This is a header}
    \detail{This is a detail.}
    \detail{This is a detail that has too many words in it and consequently runs onto the next line of the page, and I want it to have a hanging indent.}
\end{document}
```

Wanted to put this as comment to Harish Kumar's answer but I have not enough rep for that. Anyway, since space is rubber it's better to use a fixed length. Since \, seems a bit narrow I used it twice, you can adjust to taste.

Comment: There's a reason for the rep threshold for comments, but it's not so that you can post answers that should have been comments. ;-) A mod will convert this to a comment for you. You're really close to the comment privilege (50 rep)! One solid question or answer will put you over the edge. Cheers, and thanks for spending time at TeX.SX! :-)

Comment: Using this method, I still can't seem to get the correct amount of white space on the hanging indent. It's still just a hair off.